# Autocomplete with "Name <email>" similar to Gmail app

Tags: android

I want to create an `AutoCompleteTextView` which, if the user starts typing a contact's email or name it will autocomplete "Name " from his/her contact db.

How should I join `ContactsContract.Data` and `ContactsContract.Contacts` to get this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a chunk of code from an app in production that grabs these fields. Here's what I used:

`// "query" is a cursor
final String id = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID));
final String thumbnailUrl = isv11orGreater ? query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI)) : null;
final String emailAddress = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA1));
final String name = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));`

I hope that helps!